# does pip reinstall libraries everytime when creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I know it might sound stupid, but I genuinely tried my best to understand if pip installs packages from the internet every single time or does it just clone and use the already globally installed packages when I am creating a venv?

What exactly is the difference between pip install and pip download?

What does it mean by

Collecting package <package_name>...

Using cached <package_name>...

and

Downloading <package_name>

Can someone help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip download` replaces the `--download` option to pip install, which is now deprecated and was removed in `pip 10`.

> `pip download` does the same resolution and downloading as `pip install`, but instead of installing the dependencies, it collects the downloaded distributions into the directory provided (defaulting to the current directory). This directory can later be passed as the value to `pip install --find-links` to facilitate offline or locked down package installation.

> The idea behind the `pip` cache is simple, when you install a Python package using `pip` for the first time, it gets saved on the cache. If you try to download/install the same version of the package on a second time, `pip` will just use the local cached copy instead of retrieving it from the remote register .

If you plan to use the **same version** of the package in another project then using cached packages is much faster.

But if `pip` installs the cached version of the package and you want to upgrade to the newest version of the package then you can simply upgrade by: `pip install <package_name> --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you so much...i understand now

Comment: Glad to help you. If the answer is the correct one, please mark it.